# Device manager refreshes on its own and USB devices stutter - how to tell what causes the refresh?

Tags: windows-10, usb, device-manager

I have an issue on my Windows 10 computer where the USB audio, mouse, and keyboard will occasionally stutter.  While troubleshooting this, I noticed that the stuttering is accompanied Windows Device Manager automatically refreshing itself.  I assume it is doing this in response to some hardware change that is causing the stutter.  If I can find the cause of the refreshing, I can find the cause of the stutter problem.  So...

How can I find out what is causing Device Manager to refresh?

Comment: Do you hear the familiar USB insert/removal sound too?

Comment: Maybe some of the driver conflicts..try updating all of your drivers. Check all the connections, maybe something is loose.

Comment: No isb insert/removal sound is happening. I have uninstalled and reinstalled at least some of the drivers. If I can get an answer to my original question I may be pointed in a more specific direction.